# POST thousands of vars vs. a long JSON string: what is preferrable?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, post

I need to post table values of approx 200x50 (rows, cols) from jQuery to PHP. Two options:

1) Send it as array with 10,000 vars (increasing the php.ini max_input_vars).

2) Serialize the array to a JSON string, POST it as a string and decode back in PHP on the server side.

What is preferable? Any potential problems with the option 1?

Thanks

---

PS. The update. After testing both potions on a large input tables up to 250x50 cells, it looks as the 1st option is much faster: 1-2 sec vs ~17-20sec for the JSON string.

The bottleneck is the data transfer time to the server as object-to-JSON and back transactions are almost instant (a few milliseconds).

Comment: I would definitely go with option #2. A JSON POST payload would work well and wouldn't require server config manipulation

Comment: Why don't you try both, and tell us which is better for you?

Comment: If you have repeating parameter names, those will be a big part of the data to transfer. So I’d try to keep those as short as possible, or even try to keep them out of it as much as possible (use arrays in JSON, not objects where the keys have to be repeated for every item).

Comment: #2. jSON String will be good

Comment: As above, use JSON. That's what it's there for.

Comment: I have just tested both option on a table 180 x 15. Using the JSON string makes the transaction to the server too slow: 17 sec vs 1-2 sec for the POST array option. Transactions array-JSON string and back are very fast, a few milliseconds. Can someone comment on this?

Comment: actually you can rather editing your question, you can answer your own question and mark it as answer

Comment: @user2723490 What about streaming the data? You could use WebSockets.

Comment: I don't know your setup, but is it possible to post each row as it's completed by the user?

Comment: You should also consider that the name of the 10,000 vars.
Other than the index ( that i don't know if is numeric or just empty ) the name you can make as short as you want `"name=a[]"` value="xxx".The json encoding of the array , string, and quoting and everything will anyway be long. Also i don't know if you can hit some string limit in converting to json string manipulation in javascript.

Comment: It's hard to believe that json encoding it is slower. It's also hard to believe you have a legitimate case where you need to submit 10,000 variables. Is this some sort of database editor where you present thousands of rows to the user and submit the whole thing on save?

Comment: Yes, the user is given an excel-type spreadsheet, where each cell represents a value. Some financial data. Upon submitting the sheet, these values are saved in the database. It is not json encoding is slower, but the time of transferring data in multi-vars or json is diffefrent. json encoded array is too slow. If it is hard to believe - test yourself.

Comment: Json is the best option to send large data instead of thousands variables..

Comment: The thing that is hard to believe is you're still sending roughly the same amount of a data over the wire, whether it be in POST requests or as a large JSON object. I suppose converting it to a JSON object will increase the character count somewhat, but not by the order of magnitude of 20 seconds.

Comment: How are you encoding / decoding the JSON? If you use the built-in json_encode() / json_decode(), this should be as fast, if not faster, than parsing 10,000 separate variables.

Comment: You should send only if modified and modify only those data... re-saving so much not-changed data is just bad design...

Comment: Yes, i agree with @jave.web Improve your design and save only whats required!

Answer (score 0):

I send PUT requests to our server with binary data in the body, probably comparable to 10k text records and the transfer is very fast.  I would probably wonder what was going on there, whether something might be misleading you in the transfer times of one vs another.  For example the post vars might consider the "transfer" to be different phases of the request.  Or perhaps if you added a lot of extraneous baggage to the json structure with row/column names or something?

If that turned out to be true and each method has equivalent performance - I personally would go with structured JSON in the body because it seems cleaner and easier to view/debug vs a bunch of coded post variable names.

Also - I have no idea what your app does so your approach may be totally appropriate.  But I might look into figuring out if it was possible send data as-needed rather than sending an entire table all at once.  (I get annoyed when people won't answer my question and try to give me some alternative method for doing things, so take this last bit with a grain of salt!  But it does seem unusual that a human would have touched 10k records - requiring them to all be sent to the server at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered your own question. 
There is a reasonable compromise between performance and Quality of code that should be used while developing Software.

So Json is supported on both side (Javascript and PHP), and provides a better struture in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many factors. On which environment are you working, the server and client are they on the same PC ? 
Do you have to do this every day or hour ?

Are other projects on the same server so they can respond slower ? In one or two months do you will have more then 10K of vars ?

If you post the data like in the first option, since `Javascript` is faster then `PHP` you can some times loose some data.

If you may do it asynchronously, look for `RabitMQ` it's a Messaging Server that do staff when the server is ready (it does it fast too!) 
http://www.rabbitmq.com/

Answer (score 0):

Serialise it to a JSON string but use json_encode() and json_decode() since it is a lot faster. Put the variables into an object and then serialise it.

Also, javascript should do more work since it would be the client doing it, which would not put the server under such heavy load.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a variant of option #1. JSON encoders and decoders are known to be buggy and have cross-platform issues, but posting thousands of variables could be a problem. Instead you can pass all of your post variables as a single application/x-www-form-urlencoded post variable and then decode them in PHP with parse_str().

Javascript:

```
data = "data="+escape("v[0][0]="+escape(v[0][0]));
```

PHP:

```
parse_str($_POST['data'],$data);
```